# Is it possible to expand/collapse items in MaterialListComponent

Tags: angular-components, angular-dart

Is it possible to expand/collapse items in MaterialListComponent? I have noticed there is mentioning in https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/#/material_list

> If the material-list-item has a DropdownHandle in its ancestry, the
> dropdown will be closed on triggering (i.e. clicking or pressing
> enter/space on) the list item if closeOnActivate is true.

Does it mean I can create parent item and expand/collapse nested elements? Can you guys share with example if it is possible?

Comment: what do you need exactly ? something similar to [material-tree](https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/#/material_tree)   ?  or [expansion panel](https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/#/material_expansion_panel) ? .

Comment: `DropdownHandle` is mainly use by [MaterialDropdown](https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/#/material_dropdown_select) to autoclose the dropdown when clicking on list item

Comment: I need to implement drawer menu in App Layout. Items in menu should be collapsable.

Comment: I think expansion panel with material list inside can work. Will try this approach

Answer (score 0):

I have achived required behaviour with `material-expansionpanel` inside `material-list`(Thanks to @Hadrien Lejard suggestion). Here is example:

```
<material-list *deferredContent>
    <material-list-item [routerLink]="'parent/dashboard'" id="parents_listitem_dashboard">
        <material-icon icon="store"></material-icon>Dashboard
    </material-list-item>
    <material-expansionpanel flat [showSaveCancel]="false">
        <div class="expansionHeader" name id="parents_listitem_kits">
            <material-icon icon="all_inbox"></material-icon><span>Items</span>
        </div>
        <material-list-item [routerLink]="'parent/items/reserved'" id="parents_listitem_reserved">
            <material-icon></material-icon>Reserved
        </material-list-item>
        <material-list-item [routerLink]="'parent/kits/registered'" id="parents_listitem_registered">
            <material-icon></material-icon>Registered
        </material-list-item>
    </material-expansionpanel>
</material-list>
```